# How to add ssh key to project in GCP

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add my public ssh-key to my project but can't seem to make it work.
According to documentation : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys?hl=fr#project-wide ; after creating my ssh txt file I need to use the command :

```
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=[LIST_PATH]
```

I named my ssh txt file "ssh.txt" and my full path was to file was : C:\Users\33768\Desktop\ssh.txt .

I tried the following commands :

```
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=C:\Users\33768\Desktop\ssh.txt
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata-from-file ssh-keys="C:\Users\33768\Desktop\ssh.txt"
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=C:/Users/33768/Desktop/ssh.txt
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata-from-file ssh-keys="C:/Users/33768/Desktop/ssh.txt"
```

Yet, none of them worked, error being :

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.project-info.add-metadata) Unable to read file [LIST_PATH]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: [LIST_PATH]
```

where I replaced the actual list path that command line tool showed by [LIST_PATH].
Please someone help, I am getting crazy.
Thx.

Comment: The metadata file requires a specific format. what is the content of ssh.txt? Mask to hide the actual key.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone.
I actually found why it was not working. I used ubuntu for windows and that messed up the path of my folders. Inside the ubuntu terminal, I do not have access to folder in my local machine that are not on my ubuntu folder. 
Just ran my commands outside of ubuntu terminal and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

From your post I see you use Windows. I don't know how you generate your keys so I will write down everything starting from this procedure.

Download Putty (it also includes PuttyGen). Run PuttyGen, change "comment" field to your username@somemachine and click "Generate" button. After some "mouse moving" you will get your personal SSH-key which looks something like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAtJqgJA1MLB7ZqIL+xF0cnZaXyGW9LYxlyj/JrK/eOkgvRN36zI7xJc1ML5uO2Hn+EPiTwKO5+0xmwomZKnu2nrCsuZzQZakGWHiyKBYSQ1x+l+PqISOniiHOGTHc0p//lwbCLKO7bUUYuS2+7Uw3lNhKytnNA7WbcfMmm+NTH2C8ZdWptWaGmX/Yt1kdUKFCyTLAlXqdoNyr4QssdaMo4BY07JUrYHGN8Uzt7/Knd6zqqsK4Hzf0lTzxYdiuP3Y6qYBcAMtLs7iaEibu8r/i1Js7DpSHQTUYbQ6lWBk7p1yI8XJ809FTXLy20doF3ElQjBrqk/dkDk1p3AV2RlplYQ== username@somemachine
```

Click "save public key" and save it on some directory. After that "save private key" - ideally to the same directory.

You have your keys generated and saved.

Now - add them to your GCP project. Easiest ways are:

- console - go to Compute Engine > Metadata > [SSH Keys](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/metadata/sshKeys) - click "Edit" button and then "Add item". Copy your entire SSH key string into this box and click "save".
- gcloud SDK - `gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=your_file_name/name/and/path` - when adding you might get a warning `The following key(s) are missing the <username> at the front` - don't worry - they will still work.

If in doubt just read the documentation [how to add private SSH-keys to your GCP project](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys). It's a bit long but everythin's explained in detail.

Furthermore - I generated keys on Linux, added them the same way to my project and it also works.

Answer (score 0):

@John Hanley: [LIST_PATH], or ssh.txt in this case, is the concatenation in a single file of all the public keys (.pub) to upload as metadata.